# Flutter - Use contextMenuBuilder instead of toolbarOptions to disable Textfield interactions

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

Since the upgrade to Flutter 3.x the use of `toolbarOptions` has been deprecated and `contextMenuBuilder` was introduced, I found some documentations regarding its use but can't find any docs concerning how to use it to prevent interactions.

The question is I have some parameters set to `toolbarOptions` and I want to migrate those params to `contextMenuBuilder` but I couldn't make it so

```
toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
    copy: false,
    cut: false,
    paste: false,
    selectAll: false,
),
```

I tried setting `null` to `children` but it still shows the copy/paste buttons

```
contextMenuBuilder: (context, editable) {
    return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar(
        anchors: editable.contextMenuAnchors, 
        children: null
    );
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I am only using

```
enableInteractiveSelection: false
```

without adding any contextmenu to the textField

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can remove Cut option.

Similar you can adjust for other options.
This is from official documentation:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/context-menus

```
TextField(
          contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
            final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems =
                editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems;
            buttonItems.removeWhere((ContextMenuButtonItem buttonItem) {
              return buttonItem.type == ContextMenuButtonType.cut;
            });
            return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
              anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
              buttonItems: buttonItems,
            );
          },
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
TextField(
  contextMenuBuilder: null
)
```

which (in my experiments) have the same effect as `toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(...everything false)` in the old days.

Note that providing a `null` is indeed different from never providing it, since the latter will yield a default non-null value.